# I want to retrieve videos from firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on simple firebase app in which I upload user info as registration data and uploading videos in storage. Path of videos is also stored in realtime database as nested child of every particular user which is working properly, but I don't know how to retrieve video and set in user profile with other user information. I need code to retrieve video from storage.

```
     case PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


                selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
               userUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
                StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
                filename = data.getData().getLastPathSegment();
                tv_file_path.setText(filename);
                videoRef = storageRef.child("/videos/" + userUid + "/" + filename);
                //TODO: save the video in the db


            }
            break;




`//Button upload data in firebase
    btn_upload_notes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            uploadData(selectedVideoUri);


                           try {
                               if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().equals(value.getT_email())) {

                                   file_name = filename;
                                   notes_Category = text;
                                   lecture_topic = et_topic.getText().toString().trim();
                                   id = mDatabase.push().getKey();
                                   NotesModelClass notesModelClass = new NotesModelClass(id, notes_Category, lecture_topic, file_name);
                                   mDatabase.child(value.getT_id()).child("Video Notes").child(id).setValue(notesModelClass);
                                   return;
                               }
                           }
                           catch (Exception ex){
                               throw  ex;
                           }

        }
    });
```

`

```
     private void uploadData(Uri videoUri) {
    if (videoUri != null) {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();
        UploadTask uploadTask = videoRef.putFile(videoUri);

        uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot
                        .getTotalByteCount());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int) progress + "%");
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nothing to upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

Retrive single video.

```
StorageReference videoRef = storageRef.child("/videos/" + userUid + "/" + filename);

final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
videoRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
        // Transform bytes to a video, play
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Retrieve multiple video

```
 StorageTask<UploadTask.TakeSnapshot> storageTask;
        storageTask = yourStorageRefernce.putFile(videoUri);
        storageTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }
                return yourStorageRefernce.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    arrayList.add(downloadUri.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Most Welcome ^_^

Comment: I have multiple videos in every single user folder i want to retrieve all of them at once to add in arraylist and then further use them according to requirments

Comment: what should be "videoUri" value . if i am setting path in storage reference .

Comment: The value of videoUri is the uri which you pass in the method parameter. `private void uploadData(Uri videoUri) {
    if (videoUri != null) {`

Comment: I dont understand exactly what to do with videoUri if i am already setting path to "mstorageRef". If i set storage path to videosUri then it ask for typecasting to"UploadTask".

Comment: I have "videos/" as parent folder in storage then "userEmail/"as child folder then inside it i have multiple videos. now i am trying to compare email first if its match then retrieve its all videos and add in array using model class.

Comment: In my code `storageTask` is same as your code `UploadTask uploadTask = videoRef.putFile(videoUri);`
only name is change so try this

Comment: videoUri= to what . that i don't understand exactly. if you don't mind please clear me confusion.

Comment: In your code what you pass in videoUri?`UploadTask uploadTask = videoRef.putFile(videoUri);`this is same pass in my code

Comment: Could you please share your code of that class which perform that whole task.

Answer (score 0):

Help me random video in firebase

```
private void loadVideosFromFirebase() {

    videoArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseReference reb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Videos");
    reb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ModelVideo modelVideo = ds.getValue(ModelVideo.class);
                videoArrayList.add(modelVideo);

            }
            adapterVideo = new AdapterVideo(VideosActivity.this,videoArrayList);
            videosRv.setAdapter(adapterVideo);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please explain your code and why it solves this issue? Thanks!

Comment: can you help me output random video from firebase by fixing another code, ModelVideo is seter and getter (String id, String title, String timestamp, String videoUrl), RecyclerView videosRv, AdapterVideo is video playback handler